Index present, Compass insists it's not there
On a pretty large collection of 150M+ documents, I added a partial index (using the cmd line in Compass). Deployment is in a 3-member replicaset.
After quite some time, the prompt returned (ie it's done).
Checking db.transactions.getIndexes():
{
v: 2,
key: { recognized_sender_id: 1 },
name: 'recognized_sender_id_1',
partialFilterExpression: { recognized_sender_id: [Object] }

}
This makes me believe the index is present in the collection.
However, the following query (to test if the index is used):
[
  {
    $match: {
      recognized_sender_id: {
        $exists: false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $count: "count"
  }
]

Gives the following explain() result:
No index available for this query.
with raw output:
{
  "explainVersion": "2",
  "stages": [
    {
      "$cursor": {
        "queryPlanner": {
          "namespace": "db.transactions",
          "indexFilterSet": false,
          "parsedQuery": {
            "recognized_sender_id": {
              "$not": { "$exists": true }
            }
          },
          "queryHash": "2261E7A1",
          "planCacheKey": "988D5B54",
          "maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached": false,
          "maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached": false,
          "maxScansToExplodeReached": false,
          "winningPlan": {
            "queryPlan": {
              "stage": "GROUP",
              "planNodeId": 2,
              "inputStage": {
                "stage": "COLLSCAN",
                "planNodeId": 1,
                "filter": {
                  "recognized_sender_id": {
                    "$not": { "$exists": true }
                  }
                },
                "direction": "forward"
              }
            },
            "slotBasedPlan": {
              "slots": "$$RESULT=s11 env: { s4 = 1726317116455 (NOW), s3 = Timestamp(1726317115, 5) (CLUSTER_TIME), s2 = Nothing (SEARCH_META), s1 = TimeZoneDatabase(America/Godthab...America/Creston) (timeZoneDB) }",
              "stages": "[2] project [s11 = newObj(\"_id\", s10, \"count\", s8)] \n[2] project [s10 = null] \n[2] group [] [s8 = sum(1)] spillSlots[s9] mergingExprs[sum(s9)] \n[1] filter {!(\n    let [\n        l1.0 = s5 \n    ] \n    in exists(l1.0) \n)} \n[1] scan s6 s7 none none none none lowPriority [s5 = recognized_sender_id] @\"5705dc95-94eb-42f8-aa84-dfd73e12a659\" true false "
            }
          },
          "rejectedPlans": []
        },
        "executionStats": {
          "executionSuccess": true,
          "nReturned": 1,
          "executionTimeMillis": 397355,
          "totalKeysExamined": 0,
          "totalDocsExamined": 150648462,
          "executionStages": {
            "stage": "project",
            "planNodeId": 2,
            "nReturned": 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 397284,
            "opens": 1,
            "closes": 1,
            "saveState": 151313,
            "restoreState": 151313,
            "isEOF": 1,
            "projections": {
              "11": "newObj(\"_id\", s10, \"count\", s8) "
            },
            "inputStage": {
              "stage": "project",
              "planNodeId": 2,
              "nReturned": 1,
              "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 397284,
              "opens": 1,
              "closes": 1,
              "saveState": 151313,
              "restoreState": 151313,
              "isEOF": 1,
              "projections": { "10": "null " },
              "inputStage": {
                "stage": "group",
                "planNodeId": 2,
                "nReturned": 1,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 397284,
                "opens": 1,
                "closes": 1,
                "saveState": 151313,
                "restoreState": 151313,
                "isEOF": 1,
                "groupBySlots": [],
                "expressions": {
                  "8": "sum(1) ",
                  "initExprs": { "8": null }
                },
                "mergingExprs": {
                  "9": "sum(s9) "
                },
                "usedDisk": false,
                "spills": 0,
                "spilledBytes": 0,
                "spilledRecords": 0,
                "spilledDataStorageSize": 0,
                "inputStage": {
                  "stage": "filter",
                  "planNodeId": 1,
                  "nReturned": 16458274,
                  "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 396086,
                  "opens": 1,
                  "closes": 1,
                  "saveState": 151313,
                  "restoreState": 151313,
                  "isEOF": 1,
                  "numTested": 150648462,
                  "filter": "!(\n    let [\n        l1.0 = s5 \n    ] \n    in exists(l1.0) \n) ",
                  "inputStage": {
                    "stage": "scan",
                    "planNodeId": 1,
                    "nReturned": 150648462,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 390213,
                    "opens": 1,
                    "closes": 1,
                    "saveState": 151313,
                    "restoreState": 151313,
                    "isEOF": 1,
                    "numReads": 150648462,
                    "recordSlot": 6,
                    "recordIdSlot": 7,
                    "fields": [
                      "recognized_sender_id"
                    ],
                    "outputSlots": [5]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "allPlansExecution": []
        }
      },
      "nReturned": 1,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 397284
    },
    {
      "$project": { "count": true, "_id": false },
      "nReturned": 1,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 397284
    }
  ],
  "serverInfo": {
    "host": "219a25ee14ca",
    "port": 27017,
    "version": "7.0.14",
    "gitVersion": "ce59cfc6a3c5e5c067dca0d30697edd68d4f5188"
  },
  "serverParameters": {
    "internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes": 104857600,
    "internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes": 104857600,
    "internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS": 0,
    "internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes": 104857600,
    "internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes": 104857600,
    "internalQueryFrameworkControl": "trySbeRestricted"
  },
  "command": {
    "aggregate": "transactions",
    "pipeline": [
      {
        "$match": {
          "recognized_sender_id": {
            "$exists": false
          }
        }
      },
      { "$count": "count" }
    ],
    "cursor": {},
    "maxTimeMS": 60000,
    "$db": "db"
  },
  "ok": 1,
  "$clusterTime": {
    "clusterTime": {
      "$timestamp": "7414477260847054896"
    },
    "signature": {
      "hash": "EjsFtnU/ZH/DQKxb8I6ZYkdqbFU=",
      "keyId": {
        "low": 1,
        "high": 1712009831,
        "unsigned": false
      }
    }
  },
  "operationTime": {
    "$timestamp": "7414477260847054896"
  }
}

Pretty stumped about this? I have a few other indices on this collection that work perfectly. Any pointers?

What is inside of [Object] from the partialFilterExpression? The query not using an index is not directly the same thing as evidence that the index is not present.

How can I tell? I've created the index using db.transactions.createIndex({"recognized_sender_id": 1},  {partialFilterExpression: { "recognized_sender_id": { $exists: true } }}), if that helps.
I'm used to creating sparse indices, but read here that partial is better?

Well there's your answer.  The index is only capturing documents that match the condition { "recognized_sender_id": { $exists: true } }  whereas your query is specifically looking for the opposite { $match: { recognized_sender_id: { $exists: false } } }. If the database used your index then you would get incorrect results.
